# How to Make Java Process Builder Append Output to Output File?

Tags: java, file, append, processbuilder

How can I make Java's `ProcessBuilder` append the data in the output file? what it does now is that each time it writes in the output file, it deletes whatever is in it, then writes.

Comment: `pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It might be worth pointing out that's a new class in 1.7, which might be why the OP missed it or even might not be able to use it.

Comment: @millimoose Well, then it's time to upgrade ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer IT/Operations love hearing that one. Cracks them up every time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is how you create your FileWriter -- you must use the constructor that has a second boolean parameter. If the boolean, which stands for "append", is true, the file is appended to and not overwritten.

The [FileWriter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).